# How does one develop a web based sandbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, sandbox, projects-and-solutions

I want to develop an interactive website that involves the use a sandbox.I have given examples below of what the project may look like;

http://tryhaskell.org/ 
or
http://www.codecademy.com/#!/exercises/0

I'm not sure which is the best language to use for developing a sandbox.I believe that JavaScript would be suitable.

Recommendations on how to learn to develop a basic sandbox or guides/books would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you look at the network traffic you will see that your code will be submitted to the webserver (where it is probably executed in a locked down process). There is no sandbox written in Javascript on those websites.

Comment: JavaScript is the only cross-browser solution for building interactive features in a website without the need of third-party plugins like Flash, Silverlight, etc.

Comment: Thank you for an explanation of what JavaScript does...So if I wanted to implement a sandbox...how would one go about doing it.

Comment: The simplest way to implement the feature your are looking for would be to communicate with a server-side process using Ajax or WebSockets. A more complex solution would involve writing your own interpreter in JS.